# Ошибка CS1061 в проекте

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Но я только недавно начал изучать c#.По практике в техникуме нужно сделать Пинг Понг. Хочу чтобы при достижении определенного кол-ва очков, выходила другая форм в которой было написано, какой игрок победил. Но не могу передать данные из переменных form1 в wpfresult(это form2).
Выходит: Ошибка CS1061  "Form" не содержит определения "w1", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "w1", принимающий тип "Form" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку) То что погуглил почему-то не работает.

Form1

```
 using System;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace PingPong
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    
    int speedx;
    int speedy;
    int w1;
    int w2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        speedx = 4;
        speedy = 4;

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = pong1.Left;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            pong1.Left += 20;

        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            pong1.Left += -20;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            pong2.Left += 20;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            pong2.Left += -20;
        }

        if (x < 0)
        {
            pong1.Left = 0;
        }
        if (x > 470)
        {
            pong1.Left = 469;
        }
        int x1 = pong2.Left;

        if (x1 < 0)
        {
            pong2.Left = 0;
        }
        if (x1 > 470)
        {
            pong2.Left = 469;
        }


    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pong3.Left = pong3.Left + speedx;
        pong3.Top = pong3.Top + speedy;
        if (pong3.Top <= 0)
        {
            speedy = -speedy;
        }
        if (pong3.Left <= 0)
        {
            speedx = -speedx;
        }
        if (pong3.Left >= 530)
        {
            speedx = -speedx;
        }
        if (pong3.Top >= 465)
        {
            speedy = -speedy;
        }
        if ((pong3.Left + pong3.Width >= pong1.Left) & (pong3.Left <= pong1.Left + pong1.Width) & (pong1.Top + pong1.Height >= pong3.Top))
        {
            speedy = -speedy;
        }
        if ((pong3.Left + pong3.Width >= pong2.Left) & (pong3.Left <= pong2.Left + pong2.Width) & (pong3.Top + pong3.Height >= pong2.Top))
        {
            speedy = -speedy;
        }

        if (pong3.Top < 0)
        {
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text) + 1);
            w2 = int.Parse(label2.Text);
        }
        if (pong3.Top > 464)
        {
            label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text) + 1);
            w1 = int.Parse(label1.Text);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Form2

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PingPong
{
public partial class wpfresult : Form
{
    public wpfresult()
    {
        Form Form1 = new Form1();
        InitializeComponent();
        if (Form1.w1)
        {

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что нужно хотя бы сделать поле публичным и проинициализировать.

```
 public int w1 = 0;
```

Во 2-й форме опечатка. Должно быть так:

```
Form1 Form1 = new Form1(); // Тип Form1
```

Comment: Все равно та же ошибка

Comment: Выше еще написал, что тип надо поменять

Comment: Благодарю за помощь